# Flutter Web Regex-How to handle throw exception when turning on caps lock button

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, flutter-web, capslock

I am tying to use regex for validation email and password in flutter web project, here is the part of the code

```
TextField(
              onChanged: (text) {
                  bool passValid =
                      RegExp(r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{6,}$')
                          .hasMatch(text);
                  setState(() {
                    repasswordVal = passValid;
                  });
                  print(repasswordVal);
                },
                controller: _repassword,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _isHideRePassword = !_isHideRePassword;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
              labelText: "Re-enter Password",
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
              ),
            )),
```

but when I turning on the capslock keyboard, I always get this exception
[image]
actually I can ignore this exception because the project can still run correctly, but is there any solution to prevent this exception?

Comment: If you are testing it in a mac, there is already an existing issue in flutter addressing the capslock [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67866). Maybe you could follow this issue in github. In other case you can put up a MRE maybe in dartpad so we can help. :)

Comment: thankyou @AbhilashChandran, I have read the link that you gave to me, and I run my code in windows os, and haven't found any solution to prevent that exception